# reader.onload function cant read value neither call function

Tags: javascript, typescript

im using reader.onload event to get contents of csv file,

problem is the value displays in console.log() but not in DOM i.e via binding

```
dropped(event: UploadEvent) {
this.files = event.files;
console.log(this.files)
for (const droppedFile of event.files) {

  // Is it a file?
  if (droppedFile.fileEntry.isFile) {
    const fileEntry = droppedFile.fileEntry as FileSystemFileEntry;
    fileEntry.file((file: File) => {

      // Here you can access the real file
      console.log(droppedFile.relativePath, file);
      const fileToRead = file;
      const fileReader = new FileReader();
      fileReader.onload = this.onFileLoad;
      fileReader.readAsText(fileToRead);
      console.log(this.tempval) /// undefined 
    });
  } 
}}
```

and onFileLoad function is as follows

```
onFileLoad(fileLoadedEvent) {
const textFromFileLoaded = fileLoadedEvent.target.result;         
this.csvContent = textFromFileLoaded;
var allTextLines = this.csvContent.split(/\r\n|\n/);
    var headers = allTextLines[0].split(',');
var lines = [];
    for ( var i = 0; i < allTextLines.length; i++) {
        // split content based on comma
        var data = allTextLines[i].split(',');
        if (data.length == headers.length) {
            var tarr = [];
            for ( var j = 0; j < headers.length; j++) {
                tarr.push(data[j]);
            }
            lines.push(tarr);
        }
    }this.tempval = linesconsole.log(this.tempval) // printing value
```

};

unfortunately  data inside this.tempval is not accessible anywhere 
not in html DOM or inside dropped() funtion. except inside onFileLoad()

im just new to typescript

thanks in advance

Comment: Where you have appended the file text in the innerHtml of an element

Comment: try `fileReader.onload = this.onFileLoad.bind(this);`

Comment: @Shubham ".bind(this)" worked. Thanks